# angular bootstrap modal masks forms

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to get at an angular form in scope to verify validations etc.

**Base Case**

Let us say I have the following HTML:

```
 <body ng-controller='MyAwesomeController'>
   <form name="fooForm">
     <textarea ng-model="reason" required=""></textarea>
   </form>
   <div class='btn btn-primary' ng-click="submit()" ng-class="{'btn-disabled': true}">Awesome Submit Button</div>
 </body>
```

And the following controller

```
 angular.module('MyAwesomeController', '$scope', function(scope){
   scope.submit = function(){
      console.debug(scope)
   }
 })
```

This will work, and upon inspection, `scope` will contain a `fooForm` key.

Let us now say that I introduce an angular ui bootstrap modal into the mix like so:

**Broken Case**

```
 <body ng-controller="AwesomeParentController">
   <div class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="open()">Open the Modal</div>
 </body>
```

with the following two controllers:

```
.controller('AwesomeParentController', ['$scope', '$modal', function(scope, modal){
   scope.open = function(){
     options = {
       windowClass: 'modal discontinue-modal',
       templateUrl: 'modal.html',
       controller: 'AwesomeModalController'
     }
     modalInstance = modal.open(options)

     modalInstance.result.then(function(){
       console.debug("result!")
     })
   }  
 }])

 .controller("AwesomeModalController", ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function(scope, modalInstance){
   scope.submit = function(){
     console.debug(scope)
   }  
 }])
```

with the following modal.html:

```
<form name="fooForm">
  <textarea ng-model="reason" required=""></textarea>
</form>
<div class='btn btn-primary' ng-click="submit()">Awesome Submit Button</div>
```

When the first button is clicked, a modal opens, the second button click prints a `scope`, which does NOT contain `fooForm`, rather `fooForm` resides on `scope.$$childTail`

Plunkr: http://embed.plnkr.co/jFGU0teIbL3kUXdyTPxR/preview

**Possible Fix**

```
<form name="fooForm">
  <div ng-controller ="JankyFormController">
    <textarea ng-model="reason" required=""></textarea>
    <div class='btn btn-primary' ng-click="submit()">Awesome Submit Button</div>  
  </div>
</form>

.controller('JankyFormController', ['$scope', function(scope){
  scope.models['fooForm'] = scope.fooForm
}])
```

Plunkr: http://embed.plnkr.co/BAZFbS7hFRhHm8DqOpQy/preview

Why is the form being masked? What would be a clean way to get at it without having to create a nested child controller? what if I want to bind `ng-class` to the forms validity? Would I now have to construct a watch around `($$childTail).fooForm.$valid`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** angular ui-bootstrap 0.12.0 fixes the problem - transclusion scope becomes the same as controller's scope, no need for `$parent.`. Just upgrade.

**Before 0.12.0**:

Angular-UI modals are using transclusion to attach modal content, which means any new scope entries made within modal are created in child scope. This happens with form directive.

This is known issue: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/969

I proposed the quick workaround which works for me, with Angular 1.2.16:

```
<form name="$parent.userForm">
```

The `userForm` is created and available in modal's controller `$scope`. Thanks to scope inheritance `userForm` access stays untouched in the markup.

```
<div ng-class="{'has-error': userForm.email.$invalid}"}>
```

Comment: Great! quoted your answer in a related question at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26118028/2173380, but if you answer there I will choose as right answer :)

Comment: Soon there will be new release which fixes the issue by merging scopes.