# Can't access form values in a $modalInstance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm opening a `$modalInstance` in which user has to choose an option from radio inputs (values loaded dynamically) and return chosen value.

I have this function to open the `$modalInstance`:

```
$scope.openAddFriendGroup = function () {
  var addFriendGroupModal = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: "addFriendGroupModal.html",
    controller: ModalAddFriendGroupCtrl,
    resolve: {
      myDetails: function () {
        return $scope.info;
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Then this is the `$modalInstance` controller:

```
var ModalAddFriendGroupCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, myDetails, groupsSvc) {
  $scope.addableFriends = [];
  $scope.chosenFriend = null;

  //here goes a function to retrieve value of $scope.addableFriends upon $modalInstance load

  $scope.addFriend = function () {
    $scope.recording = true;

    groupsSvc.addFriend($scope.chosenFriend, myDetails).then(function (response) {
      if(response.status && response.status == 200) {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.userid);
      }
    }, function (err) {
      $modalInstance.dismiss(err);
    });
  };
};
```

And this is `addFriendGroupModal.html`, the HTML for the modal itself:

```
<div id="add-friend-group-modal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Add friend</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form" role="form" ng-hide="loading">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Friend:</label>
        <div class="radio" ng-repeat="thisFriend in addableFriends">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" id="friend{{thisFriend.id}}" name="chosenFriend" ng-model="$parent.chosenFriend" ng-value="thisFriend" /> {{thisFriend.name}} {{thisFriend.surname}}
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addFriend()">Add friend</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, the problem comes when I try to retrieve the value that has been selected in the radio buttons of the form in the modal. I can't seem to retrieve this value in `$scope.addFriend`. The value of `$scope.chosenFriend` stays at `null` and does not get updated when selecting a radio option.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [angular bootstrap modal masks forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213343/angular-bootstrap-modal-masks-forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieved [answer from a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23044860/2173380), by **gertas**

> Angular-UI modals are using transclusion to attach modal content, which means any new scope entries made within modal are created in child scope. This happens with form directive.
>
> This is known issue: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/969
>
> I proposed the quick workaround which works for me, with Angular 1.2.16:
>
> ```
>   <form name="$parent.userForm">
> ```
>
> The `userForm` is created and available in modal's controller `$scope`. Thanks to scope inheritance `userForm` access stays untouched in the markup.
>
> ```
>   <div ng-class="{'has-error': userForm.email.$invalid}"}>
> ```

So, in my form I would have to set a `name="$parent.friendForm"` attribute to `<form>`, and then bind the radio button model to it, `ng-model="friendForm.chosenFriend"` to be able to read it from the modal scope at `$scope.friendForm.chosenFriend`.

Answer (score 0):

`$modal.open` returns promise so try :

```
 var addFriendGroupModal;

 $modal.open({ ...})
  .result.then(function(response){
      addFriendGroupModal  = response;
   });
```

Comment: I don't think you have understood my question. The problem is that the value of `chosenFriend` is not getting updated inside the modal's scope according to the option chosen in the modal form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" id="friend{{thisFriend.id}}" name="chosenFriend" ng-model="$parent.chosenFriend" ng-value="thisFriend" /> {{thisFriend.name}} {{thisFriend.surname}}
```

in here your `ng-model` is `$parent.chosenFriend` so, why are you expecting `$scope.chosenFriend` to not be a null? change you ng-model property to `$scope.chosenFriend`.

Comment: I have removed `$parent` from `ng-model` and I still receive `null` as if the form is not updating the value. However the `$parent` thingy is related to radio buttons creating a sub scope in angular.